# How *does* Powerbuilder POST work?

Tags: post, sybase, powerbuilder

Unfortunately searching for 'Sybase Post' doesn't get me the answers I'm looking for.

I want to know what the actual function is of POST

As in

```
.. procedure lala
POST procedure1()
procedure2()
```

I'm guessing in the above code, procedure2 would be executed before procedure1, that's fine.

But when is it processed? After everything else is done? Why do you use POST, and when is it appropriate? Can POST lose the context of the row and dw that you are trying to process?

Any linking to the right Sybase Info source would be grand, cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not an T-SQL keyword, but a PowerBuilder one.

Here's the [Sybase explanation](http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=42067).

Comment: I think it's the lack of sleep, but I looking at the Powerbuilder code, and not registering it was PB, but sybase. No wonder I didn't get any google hits :$